# How to use achor link on route react in the best way

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi i've an apps you can access it thorugh https://selly-midtrans.herokuapp.com/ but if you click the `clients` menu from other page eg: you're in page `features` and you click the `clients` menu . then the apps will directly navigate to `home#client` but after that react will re rendering the apps.

so my question how to stop react to re rendering if we have already go to some section as my website did ,

my index file

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')); 
registerServiceWorker();
```

my router file(this file imported to apps.js)

```
class Routing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>        
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/index" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/client" component={Client} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route path="/features" component={Feature} />
            <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
            <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

my navigation

```
<li><a href='features'>Features</a></li>
<li><a href='home#clients'>Clients</a></li>
<li><a href='faq'>Support</a></li>
<li><a href='contact'>Contact</a></li>
```

and i've already try using `Link` tag but when i using that , it redirect to section `#client` but the apps not rendered completely

Answer (score 1):

your router is configured correctly otherwise you would not be able to navigate to any views. By using a href like you are currently are the page will always refresh so use must use the Link tag. It sounds like an issue more with your rendering/component life cycle methods if the page does render correctly with a Link tag.

You will need to explain further how the page does not render correctly when using a Link tag.

Comment: Here is the normal UI for `/home#clients` https://imgur.com/a/UavfZ and https://imgur.com/ZVzVHAJ after i using Link tag. beside that if i navigate to `/home#clients` it only redirect me to the top of home page , not the `clients` section